# Will install Watch App called with bad bundle identifier '(null)'

Tags: watchos-2, xcode7-beta5

When I use xcode 7 beta 5 and wanna to run a simple demo on watch simulator. It prompts this "Will install Watch App called with bad bundle identifier '(null)'". I cannot find it anywhere. Does anyone know this?

Comment: After add iOS target to Build target. The problem solved.

Comment: I have the same problem for Xcode7 beta5.I choose the watchKit App for the build target but nothing help.

Comment: Tab you scheme->Edit Scheme->Build->+
Add you app, watch app and watch extension there. I think it will be fine.

Comment: The final scheme should be something like this:
https://drive.google.com/a/umn.edu/file/d/0B_N0iePPjbEjWXh1TDYyU0NwWEk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you, @Michael. I had the similar problem. Your advice helped me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that the iOS app is not compiled when Xcode tries to launch the Apple Watch App + Extension.

In order to solve this problem, as said in the comments of the question, add the iOS App to the Build Target (edit scheme, select the `Build` entry, and add the iOS target).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved the problem by creating a new scheme with the correct target.
It worked without doing anything more.